# How to show filter toolbar in in 2 rows?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqxgrid

I have requirement where I need to show filter controls(like textbox, checkbox, dropdonw box) in grid. Here is the sample image[image]

Currently I am using datatable plugin.  From this only 1 filter control column is added, but it need be more than one control per column.

Please let me know if it can be achievable by using datatable plugin. Or please let me know if any other plugin are available.

I have also explored jqgrid, jqxgrid. seems like all plugin shows only one filter control per column.

Thanks

Comment: You really should explain WHY you would need multiple filters for a column so we have some direction in which to guide you please.

Comment: ok, at few columns we will be having search filed, where user can type in the text in input filed(this in bottom row), and at the same time user can choose options like {contains, startswith,endswith, exact} from the dropdown(this is in top row).

Comment: @niran - All of these features are provided by advanced search - see my updated answer. Does that help at all?

Comment: Correct, But it is a popup. it need to be under the column header

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid does not support a second row of filters, but it does have advanced searching which lets you achieve the same thing:

[image]

From here you can use the `+` button to add multiple filter criteria. For example you could search by `Inv No == 1` OR `Inv No == 2`. This accomplishes what having two rows of filter toolbar would achieve, but with the power to specify AND/OR, as many criteria as necessary, etc. The UI may be more complicated than in your example, but a more advanced search necessitates such a compromise.

You can see a live demo online under [`Searching` | `Complex search`](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

Anyway, see the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) for more details.